# Sharepoint 2010 - One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know why I keep getting the following message in Sharepoint 2010 review problems and solutions list:

> The following services are managed by
> SharePoint, but their running state
> does not match what SharePoint
> expects: SPAdminV4.  This can happen
> if a service crashes or if an
> administrator starts or stops a
> service using a non-SharePoint
> interface.  If SharePoint-managed
> services do not match their expected
> running state, SharePoint will be
> unable to correctly distribute work to
> the service.
>
> Failing Services: SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)

I assume this is referring to `Sharepoint 2010 Timer Service` but I can only see this in the services msc (and it is running), not in the `Application Management > Manage services on server`.

Does anyone know why this keeps occurring and how I can stop it?

Note - I looked in the event log and all I can see is that same error.

Comment: Stopped outside the SP admin console, with Adminstrative Tools...Services, perhaps?

Comment: I'm the only one with access and I haven't stopped it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](http://mundeep.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/clearing-timer-services/) believes it's "caused by the timer job cache being in an inconsistent state" and shows how to rebuild the jobs. Another suggestion was ensuring enough disk space.

There's some [exotic solutions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/br/smallbusinessserver/thread/94a8bb64-e0ea-493f-8e29-01347b1fc6c7) as well that include re-running psconfig.